# How do I Load AGRC ArcGIS REST tile service in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, arcgis-server

How do I load this service http://mapserv.utah.gov/arcgis/rest/services/BaseMaps/Lite/MapServer in OpenLayers?  The projection is 26912 (UTM Zone 12).  Here is one of the variations I tried (without success):

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
div : "rcp1_map",
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:26912")
});

var AGRCLite = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ( "AGRC Lite",
"http://mapserv.utah.gov/arcgis/rest/services/BaseMaps/Lite/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}");
map.addLayer(AGRCLite);
```

Using the XYZ method works in this case:

```
var ESRIWorld = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ( "ESRI",
"http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}",
{sphericalMercator: true} );
```

But I can't get it to work for the AGRC service.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this resource :
[OpenLayer / Blog sathyaprasad](http://sathyaprasad.appspot.com/openlayers.html)
using OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest class must do the trick for cache services not available in the wished projection.